# Directory Shortcuts in Vim

Tags: vim, gvim

Does anyone know a good/neat way to create directory shortcuts in Vim?

Akin to the "~[shortcut]" in Zsh which you can use to quickly specify a directory.

I could create aliases in my home directory and use "~/[alias]" but it would be nice if I could have something only available in Vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cmdalias](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746) for Vim. Then you can make custom aliases such as `cdsrc` to change to a directory like `/home/user/project/source`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
let $vimfiles = "c:\\ldigas-home\\gvim72\\vim\\vimfiles"
```

so when I go

```
 cd $vimfiles
```

it puts me in

```
c:\ldigas-home\gvim72\\vim\vimfiles
```

Or did you have something else in mind ?

Comment: I never thought it is that easy. Thanks a billion man

Answer (score 2):

NerdTree provides bookmarks handling. See ":h NerdTreeBookmarks".

While not directly accessible via ":cd", there is at least ":NERDTreeFromBookmark", where you can then "cd" to this (or another dir).

Also "B" in the NERDTree window will toggle display of bookmarks, and allows to easily access them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a FavEx plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=539

Answer (score 0):

One way I solved this was by having something like this:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>hd :e ~/daisuke
```

in my .vimrc. This will populate the command with ":e ~/daisuke" with the cursor at the end. This actually suites me well as majority of the time, I want to edit a file under that directory not necessarily just cd to it (sorry should have been more clear about this!)